# Returning back parameter values

Tags: objective-c, return

I am trying to update `c01` parameter value to a new one by calling following method. However it still returns `0`.

```
[self testingmethod:c01];
```

The method body is:

```
- (void)testingmethod:(int)y {
  int x;
  x = arc4random() % 399 + 1;
  while (x == y || x == 0){
    x = arc4random() % 399 + 1;
  }
  y = x;
  return y; // is this right?
}
```

Can someone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there would be two possible ways here for you to do what you want to achieve:

## 1st idea

```
- (int)testingMethod:(int)y {
    int x;
    x = arc4random() % 399 + 1;
    while (x == y || x == 0){
        x = arc4random() % 399 + 1;
    }
    y = x;
    return y;
}
```

then

```
c01 = [self testingMethod:c01];
```

## 2nd idea

```
- (void)testingMethod:(int *)y {
    if (y) {
        int x;
        x = arc4random() % 399 + 1;
        while (x == *y || x == 0){
            x = arc4random() % 399 + 1;
        }
        *y = x;
    }
}
```

then

```
[self testingMethod:&c01];
```

Comment: The 1st option is I what I need. Thanks alot!

Comment: No need to assign `x` value to `y` before returning `y`. Just replace these two lines with `return x`.

Comment: @robertvojta, I did not want to change the original code pattern (see OP above), I only pointed out what changes should be made essentially to make the code working as the OP would expect.

Answer (score 0):

Your method signature is ...

```
- (void)testingmethod:(int)y
```

... which says this:

- there's no return value (`void`),
- name is `testingmethod`,
- it accepts one argument named `y` of type `int`.

If you would like to return an value, you have to change your method signature to ..

```
- (int)testingmethod:(int)y
```

... and method body to ...

```
- (int)testingmethod:(int)y {
  int x;
  x = arc4random()%400 + 1;
  while(x == y || x == 0){
    x = arc4random()%400 + 1;
  }
  return x;
}
```

Also do not use `arc4random()` with `%`. There's `arc4random_uniform`:

```
u_int32_t arc4random_uniform(u_int32_t upper_bound);
```

> arc4random_uniform() will return a uniformly distributed random number
>   less than upper_bound. arc4random_uniform() is recommended over
>   constructions like ``arc4random() % upper_bound'' as it avoids "modulo
>   bias" when the upper bound is not a power of two.

It leads to this code ...

```
- (int)testingmethod:(int)y {
  int x;
  x = arc4random_uniform(400) + 1;
  while(x == y || x == 0){
    x = arc4random_uniform(400) + 1;
  }
  return x;
}
```

... which can be used in this way:

```
c01 = [self testingmethod:c01];
```

This can be further optimized to ...

```
- (int)testingmethod:(int)y {
  int x;
  do {
    x = arc4random_uniform(400) + 1;
  } while(x == y);
  return x;
}
```

... because:

- `u_int32_t` is unsigned, `arc4random...` returns positive numbers (`>= 0`),
- you're adding `1` to this number, it can never be `0`, useless to check for `0`,
- `do while` is better, because there's just one line where you generate numbers and generally, `do while` is used over `while` in cases where you need to execute some statements before you compare value.

---

Why `c01` value is not modified when you do modify `y` in original example?
[Objective-C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C) is superset of C and everything what does [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29#Overview), does Objective-C as well.

> Function parameters are always passed by value. Pass-by-reference is
>   simulated in C by explicitly passing pointer values.

Do you want to simulate references, so, you can change value of `c01`? Use pointers ...

```
- (void)testingmethod:(int *)y {
  if ( y == nil ) { return; }
  int x;
  do {
    x = arc4random_uniform(400) + 1;
  } while(x == *y);
  *y = x;
}
```

Usage:

```
[self testingmethod:&c01];
```

---

Example of required number generator based on comments. Not optimized at all, for readability and proper understanding sake.

```
@interface RandomNumberGenerator: NSObject

- (NSArray *)generatorRandomNumbersWithLowerBound:(NSUInteger)lowerBound
                                       upperBound:(NSUInteger)upperBound
                                            count:(NSUInteger)count;

@end

@implementation RandomNumberGenerator

- (NSArray *)generatorRandomNumbersWithLowerBound:(NSUInteger)lowerBound
                                       upperBound:(NSUInteger)upperBound
                                            count:(NSUInteger)count {

  if ( lowerBound > upperBound ) {
    // lowerBound can't be greater than upperBound, error
    return nil;
  }

  if ( count == 0 ) {
    // number of required numbers is not > 0? error
    return nil;
  }

  if ( lowerBound == upperBound ) {
    // bounds equals
    if ( count == 1 ) {
      // equal bounds, just return one number
      return @[ @(lowerBound) ];
    } else {
      // equal bounds, but required more than one number, error
      return nil;
    }
  }

  if ( count > upperBound - lowerBound + 1 ) {
    // number of required numbers is greater than available numbers in given bounds, error
    return nil;
  }

  // arc4random_uniform generates numbers from 0, just calculate right upper bound
  NSUInteger arc4randomUpperBound = upperBound - lowerBound + 1;
  NSUInteger arc4randomAddition = lowerBound;

  // generated numbers so far
  NSMutableArray *numbers = [@[] mutableCopy];

  // loop until all required numbers are generated
  while ( numbers.count < count ) {
    NSInteger x;
    do {
      x = arc4random_uniform((u_int32_t)arc4randomUpperBound) + arc4randomAddition;
      // loop till generated number is not in already generated numbers
    } while ( [numbers indexOfObject:@(x)] != NSNotFound );
    [numbers addObject:@(x)];
  }

  return numbers;
}

@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  @autoreleasepool {
    RandomNumberGenerator *generator = [[RandomNumberGenerator alloc] init];

    NSLog( @"1-400, 10 numbers: %@",
      [generator generatorRandomNumbersWithLowerBound:1 upperBound:400 count:10]);
    NSLog( @"0-9, 10 numbers: %@",
      [generator generatorRandomNumbersWithLowerBound:0 upperBound:9 count:10]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The moment change the while, to do-while statement, the values appeared is not to my expectation. I will go with the 1st option regarding on the method that gives return value. Thanks..

Comment: And thank you for the information on the arc4random() information.. I'm currently using the arc4random_uniform(399)+1; :)

Comment: @ShafaruddinSahdion out of curiosity, what does _values appeared is not to my expectation_ mean exactly? Your `while` and my `do while` do exactly same thing. It returns random number in range 1..400 (inclusive), but not equal to passed `y` value.

Comment: I currently do not have my code here. The whole intention is to display a sets of non-repeatable number from 1-400, however when I executed the do-while statement, i saw some repetitions.I'm not really sure why.

Comment: That's because `arc4random_*` generates random numbers and these numbers can equal. And your `testingmethod` checks against one number, not the whole set (already generated). There will equal numbers for sure. It has nothing to do with `do while` or `while`. Your `testingmethod` should compare against all already generated numbers, not just one number.

Comment: Yes I did write down the comparison with the rest of other nunbers  basically from a01,a02,a03....t20. the code is too long for me to write it down here..

Comment: 1. Made a mistake, `arc4random_uniform(399)` generates numbers in range `0..398`, it should be `arc4random_uniform(400)` to generate in range `0..399` and `+1` makes it `1..400`. 2. Enhanced my answer with generic (totally not optimized) method to generate non repeatable numbers where you can pass lower / upper bound and number of required numbers.

Comment: Yes, if you'd like to have 1..400 (both bounds inclusive).